# How is the bias added after the convolution in a CNN?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, feature-extraction, bias

I'm having trouble understanding how bias is added to the feature extraction convolution. I've seen people either refer to the bias as a single number that changes per filter or the whole matrix that is the size of the output. Here is what I mean:

[image]

[image]

- $I$ is the input single-channel image.
- $F$ is the filter.
- $b$ is the bias.
- "Izhod" means "output".

Which is actually the correct bias used in CNN?

Comment: Hello. Where did you take this diagram from?

Comment: I drew it myself. The idea that bias is a single number and not a matrix came from
https://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/
under the Convolution demo where Bias is displayed as a 1x1x1 matrix.
However the idea that the bias might actually be a whole matrix that is the size of the output came from this video https://youtu.be/Lakz2MoHy6o?t=343 at the 5:00 mark.